# Get the control id of usercontrol in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on asp.net website.
In my project I'm using the usercontrols.
I have placed the radgrid inside the user controls.
I need to get the id of radgrid of usercontrol and need to enable the scrolling for the grid.
How can I achieve this.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add public property of type radgrid in your `UserControl` which will allow you to access it simply like `idOfUserControl.RadGrid.ClientID` and this is how to add property:

```
public YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    public RadGrid Grid { get; set; }

    public void Page_Load(...)
    {
         Grid = idOfRadGrid; //idOfRadGrid = id of RadGrid specified in aspx markup
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks. Myself soved by adding property to usercntrol and acces that in aspx. thanks for responcse

Comment: I think it would be better to add a property that gets the ID of the grid rather than the entire grid. Properties that get/set controls doesn't seem quite right.